# ContentType still exists after deleting SiteCollection and creating it new

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have an SharePoint SiteCollection (portal/sites/sitex) with a custom content type, which for whatever reason I can't delete (says it is in use though it isn't).

I deleted the SiteCollection in the CA (including removing it from the trash with `Remove-SPDeletedSite`) and created a new SiteCollection by the same name an URL ... and the content type is still (or again) there ... in the new SiteCollection.

If I create a SiteCollection with a different URL (portal/sites/sitey) the content type isn't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point, the content type finally was gone. I can't say, what did the trick, but I did multiple IIS resets and restarts, so maybe it was a caching problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the sites which uses the content type.
Then, you can see if you have deleted all.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david/archive/2011/08/25/powershell-script-to-locate-content-type-useage.aspx

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, the script finds 0 uses of the content type ... I tried to modify it to search by CT ID, still 0 uses.

Comment: Maybe the problem related with cache. Have you tried to clean cache?